# What type of pipe should I used to build a gravity drain from my furnace to the bathroom plumbing?

Tags: plumbing, hvac, pump

In the picture below, the existing pipe that is used by the condensate pump runs across the red line in the figure (*it does not connect exactly there but that is the idea*)

That line is a clear pvc tubing, 0.2" diameter, old and turned brownish. I want to replace it.

I don't think it is properly sized and connected as the pump needs to push twice to send the water through it. (*probably some is coming back*)
It was also explained that the purpose of a condensate pump is to pump the water up to a level and then a gravity  should take it on further.

Since this existing pipe is traversing the ceiling to get to the bathroom there is no slope and I am considering installing a drain across the blue line you see in the picture.

What material and what size should I use ? 1.5" ABS ?

Is there anything smaller like 1" or 1/2" that can be used in this case?

[image]
Update: here is the pump model -21786 in the picture below
[image]

Comment: you were editing my q :-)) while I was fixing that ..please see it now

Comment: "0.2" diameter"  is pretty small. Approximately 3/16th  that is very small. Is that correct?  can you post a photo of the pump fitting? What is the condensate pump for?

Comment: yeah I get that but what do I put there to solve the issue

Comment: There should be specs for the the unit that the pump is servicing. Have you tried finding the manual online?

Comment: see the update please

Comment: It says the check valve is 3/8" so 3/8" tubing should be correct. *3/8" is two times bigger than 3/16"*.

Comment: OD  or ID ? And what material should it be? I am not clear on how these pumps work? It says it cam pump the water 16' up

Comment: you can use any sort of pipe that is suited to water,  copper, PEX, PVC, ABS, PE etc...

Comment: I think I heard here or somewhere else that PEX is not OK since It might collapse in time if not full with water to keep it in shape